# Java AmazonS3Client constructor failing

Tags: java, javascript, amazon-s3

I have an Applet whose method gets called from a JavaScript function within a browser. This method will eventually send a file to an Amazon S3 bucket. When this method attempts to create the AmazonS3Client however, the method fails without displaying any errors.

The relevant snippet of the code within the method is:

```
InputStream input = DigitalLive.class.getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties");
System.out.println("File loaded into Input Stream.");

PropertiesCredentials theCredentials = new PropertiesCredentials(input);
System.out.println("Credentials created.");
System.out.println("AccessKey is:" + theCredentials.getAWSAccessKeyId());
System.out.println("SecretKey is:" + theCredentials.getAWSSecretKey());

//All of the above strings print to the console with the correct AccessKey and SecretKey
try{
    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(theCredentials);
    //This message never prints
    System.out.println("Client created."); 
} catch(Exception e) {
    //This message never prints
    System.err.println("Error creating AmazonClient: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

None of the messages within the try/catch block ever print. None of the rest of the method's code (not shown here for brevity) gets fired either.

The jar file compiles without error. I'm using jdk 1.7.0_51 and the amazon aws-java-sdk-1.7.1. I'm using Eclipse as the IDE and am building the jar with a build file using ANT.

I'm not really sure what else to try other than wrapping the code in a try/catch block.
Is there a different/better way for me to debug the Java code to learn why the AmazonS3Client is not created? Or perhaps a more obvious reason why it might fail given the code snippet above?

EDIT: I added a try/catch block in the JavaScript code that calls the Java method and it throws an error:

```
Error calling method on NPObject
Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

I think what this tells me that the Java Applet is in fact throwing an error. I'm just not sure how to figure out which one and how to solve it. I've attempted to put try/catch blocks around the `AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(theCredentials);` but the IDE tells me `Unreachable catch block for InvocationTargetException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body`.

Comment: Have you tried using the class instead of the interface (AmazonS3Client instead of AmazonS3)? 
    
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(theCredentials);

Comment: @sallie I just tried that now, but with the same result as before.

Comment: Another shot in the dark suggestion - try system.out instead of system.err just in case something is eating your stderr. I don't have any brilliant suggestions. Just a 'try everything' approach.

Comment: @sallie I appreciate the shots. No luck changing from 'err' to 'out'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the error message was not being written to the console when the method in question was called from within JavaScript. I modified the Applet so that the method could be called from within the Applet, and the error was displayed in the console as expected.

The Applet was missing an Apache class, so that was added and all is well.